# itext 7 how to merge Pdfs?

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a Problem and need your help. I'm running itext 7.0.2. java and i'm trying to merge a list ArrayList of type PdfDocument to one single pdf.

I tried the following:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream bosGes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter writerGes = new PdfWriter(bosGes);
        PdfDocument docGes = new PdfDocument(writerGes);
        ArrayList<PdfDocument> pdfs = AListOfSomePreviousCreatedPdfDocuments;

        for (int i=0; i < pdfs.size(); i++) {
            PdfDocument d = pdfs.get(i);
            PdfPage p = d.getFirstPage().copyTo(docGes);
            docGes.addPage(p);
            d.close();
        }
```

Resulting in this error:

**com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Cannot copy indirect object from the document that is being written.**

Then I tried the following:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream bosGes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter writerGes = new PdfWriter(bosGes);
        PdfDocument docGes = new PdfDocument(writerGes);

        for (int i=0; i < pdfs.size(); i++) {
            PdfDocument d = pdfs.get(i);
            docGes.addPage(d.getFirstPage());
            d.close();
        }
```

**com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Page com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage@1d85315f cannot be added to document com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument@32ae81bb, because it belongs to document com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument@4b8d06af.**

What I have to do, to merge this PdfDocuments (each one has only one page) to one single Pdf?

---

OK, I'm going nuts. Explaining it from the beginning.

I create pdf-forms like this

```
        ArrayList<PdfDocument> pdfs = new ArrayList<PdfDocument>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            URL fullPath = context.getResource("/formulare/kontrollbogen.pdf");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(bos);
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fullPath.getFile());
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
            PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(doc, true);

            String firma = rs.getString("firma");
            if (firma != null && !firma.equals("")) {
                form.getField("firma").setValue(firma);
            }
                .
                .
                .
            pdfs.add(doc);
       }
```

Then I want to merge this PdfDocuments in my ArrayList like this:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream bosGes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter writerGes = new PdfWriter(bosGes);
        PdfDocument resultDoc = new PdfDocument(writerGes);

        for (int i=0; i < pdfs.size(); i++) {
            PdfReader r = pdfs.get(i).getReader();
            PdfDocument sourceDoc1 = new PdfDocument(r);
            int n1 = sourceDoc1.getNumberOfPages();             

            for (int j = 1; j <= n1; j++) {
                PdfPage page = sourceDoc1.getPage(j).copyTo(resultDoc);
                resultDoc.addPage(page);
            }
            sourceDoc1.close();
        }

        resultDoc.close();
```

Doesn't work. Result is a pdf with more pages but forms are not filled out.

So I tried RTFM and tried Bruno's example with merging flattened forms but result is always a pdf with empty forms.

Can anyone help to convert the pdf-forms (all the same form) in my ArrayList to one single pdf?

---

I tried Bruno's tip but it doesn't work. What I did is:

```
        //Initialize PDF document with output intent
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writerGes);
        PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);
        //Add pages from the first document
        PdfDocument firstSourcePdf = pdfs.get(0);
        merger.merge(firstSourcePdf, 1, firstSourcePdf.getNumberOfPages());
        //Add pages from the second pdf document
        PdfDocument secondSourcePdf = pdfs.get(1);
        merger.merge(secondSourcePdf, 1, secondSourcePdf.getNumberOfPages());
        firstSourcePdf.close();
        secondSourcePdf.close();
        pdf.close();
```

but it ends up with this error again:

com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Cannot copy indirect object from the document that is being written.

Is this perhaps because my pdf's are forms and I have to reset the values when merging?

Comment: Did you read the manual? See https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-6-reusing-existing-pdf-documents and look for `PdfMerger`.

Comment: I Tried but didnt succeed. Dont Know what i am doing wrong

Comment: The code in your question is in contradiction with what you claim in your comment. The code in your question is totally different from what is shown in the tutorial, hence I can only assume that you didn't try the examples from the tutorial.

Comment: Ok. I have to try again. My Problem ist Thema following. Someone is giving me an Arraylist of pdfdocument-objects with an filled Out Formular. Each one has only one Page. I have to combine them to one pdfdocument with The Number of Pages of all documents

Comment: hey bruno, didnt work. i wrote an answer to be able to post my code. dont know what to do.

Comment: The error message *"Cannot copy indirect object from the document that is being written."* appears to indicate that the  `PdfDocument` objects you want to merge have not been created with a mere `PdfReader` but instead at least also with a `PdfWriter`.

Comment: @mkl That sounds reasonable, but what does it exactly mean? You cannot merge immediately created PDFs?

Comment: @Juergen Correct. Pdfs in the process of creation on one hand have unfinished objects (e.g. subset fonts which may get additional glyphs) and on the other hand have contents which already have been streamed to the result file and removed from memory. While for the first kind of object one could find a solution, the data not in memory anymore simply is not available to itext anymore. Thus, a pdf document with a `PdfWriter` generally is not considered save to copy from.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for clarifying :) So you need to hack around as I did: I read the byte array out of the underlying streams of the immediately created PDFs. Feed a new PdfReader with that byte array, create a PdfDocument out of it to merge it to the main Document. This is a bit hacky but works.

Comment: @Juergen it feels hacky but considering some architectural targets of itext, in particular to limit memory usage to allow easy creation of large documents, it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

this is how I merged 2 pdf documents together

```
if (1 <= listOfFiles.Count)
{
    masterSrc = subPath + "/" + date + " - " + dateEnd + ".pdf";

    PdfDocument merged = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(Server.MapPath(masterSrc)));

    for (int a = 0; a < listOfFiles.Count; a++)
    {
        PdfDocument origPdf2 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(Server.MapPath(listOfFiles[a])));
        PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(merged);
        merger.Merge(origPdf2, 1, origPdf2.GetNumberOfPages());

    }
    merged.Close();
}
```